# Change parameter values on each Spring Retry attempt

Tags: spring, spring-retry

I have following method which is @Retryable:

```
    @Retryable(value = HttpClientErrorException.class)
    public Integer callToExternalService(DateTime start, DateTime end) throws MyException
```

My question is if I can modify input parameters each time method is under retry because I need to make a rest call with different values. Is there an option similar to `@Recover` for this case?

Answer (score 3):

Not out of the box; you would need to add another advice closer to the bean than the retry interceptor to modify the `MethodInvocation.arguments`.

Or you could subclass the retry interceptor and override the `invoke` method.

Neither one is trivial, unless you have some knowledge about Spring proxies.

Here's a simpler way to do it; it will need a bit more work if you need to recover rather than throw the last exception to the caller.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So61486701Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61486701Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    MethodInterceptor argumentChanger() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3);
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOff = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOff.setBackOffPeriod(1000L);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOff);
        return invocation -> {
            return retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
                if (context.getRetryCount() > 0) {
                    Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                    args[0] = ((Integer) args[0]) + 1;
                    args[1] = ((String) args[1]) + ((String) args[1]);
                }
                return invocation.proceed();
            });
        };
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> foo.test(1, "foo.");
    }

}

@Component
class Foo {

     @Retryable(interceptor = "argumentChanger")
     public void test(int val, String str) {
        System.out.println(val + ":" + str);
        throw new RuntimeException();
     }

 }
```

Comment: So, if I want to change value each time I try to call the rest service, would it be better to just use a ```while``` or ```for``` loop instead?

Comment: I can't really answer that, but it's probably much less work.

Comment: Do you know about any documentation regarding the two options you mentions above in the answer? As you said, neither look trivial.

Comment: It would be nice if add a method like `doBeforeRetry` like [reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.5.4/api/reactor/util/retry/RetrySpec.html#doBeforeRetry-java.util.function.Consumer-) does

Comment: @GaryRussell Maybe `RetryListener.onError` from Spring Retry can fit this? It's just I don't know if the RetryListener is synchronous thus will execute in the same thread with retrying-attempts